# Mobile broadband with Huawei E1552/E1800

Tags: mobile-broadband, huawei, usb-modeswitch

I can't establish the mobile broadband connection (I created the new connection in NW) via USB 3.0 on Dell Inspiron 5520. Ubuntu 12.04.
lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800 (HSPA modem)
```

Log after inserting:

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Fri Aug 17 00:12:39 2012

Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

Raw args from udev: /3-4:1.0

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (3-4:1.0) ...
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSes, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No new devices in target mode or class found

Mode switch has failed. Bye.

fail:
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

All done, exitingI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor  12d1
  idProduct 1446
  manufacturer  HUAWEI Technology
  product   HUAWEI Mobile
  serial    (null)
  bNumConfigurations    1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1446*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1446*
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on.

Extracting config 12d1:1446 from collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProduct set to 1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
! matched, now switching
Command to be run:
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 20 -c /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg -u -1   -v 12d1 -p 1446 2>&1

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are expected in the process)
--------------------------------

Reading config file: /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg

 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 1.2.3 (C) Josua Dietze 2012
 * Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set

InquireDevice disabled
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled


Looking for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No devices in target mode or class found
Looking for default devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
   found matching product ID
   adding device
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 016 on bus 003 ...
Skipping the check for the current configuration
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
 OK, driver "usb-storage" detached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x81
Resetting message endpoint 0x01

Checking for mode switch (max. 20 times, once per second) ...
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0a5c:21d7
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0c45:648d
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0129
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No new devices in target mode or class found

Mode switch has failed. Bye.

fail:
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

All done, exiting
```

One time connection established (before it I made some random steps in BIOS), but later all became as earlier.
I found the same problems (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996734 and http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2012/02/3g-using-huawei-e1552e1800-hspa-modem.html) and made the same steps, but lsusb doesn't changes. Only one time it unexpectedly changed to 'Bus 002 Device 012: ID 12d1:14ac Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. ' (as it must be using USB 2.0) and connection established, but I dropped down the laptop and modem was disconnected. I've never got working Internet via modem since that time, lsusb shows 'Bus 003 Device 016: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800 (HSPA modem)'.

Also:

```
vladiator@vladiatro:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 1446 -V 0x12d1 -P 1446 -R
[sudo] password for vladiator: 

Looking for target devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Looking for default devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 016 on bus 003 ...
Getting the current device configuration ...
 OK, got current device configuration (1)
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
 **No driver found. Either detached before or never attached**

SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
-------------------------
  Vendor String: HUAWEI  
   Model String: Mass Storage    
Revision String: 2.31
-------------------------

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Warning: no switching method given.
Resetting usb device .
 OK, device was reset
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

lsusb doesn't change.
One time driver was found, but this program couldn't finish and I stopped it by Ctrl+C. It doesn't change anything.
Thanks,
Vladiator.

Comment: There is no USB 3.0 involved, it's just a regular USB 2.0 mobile broadband modem. That said, get a mobile hotspot like one from the Huawei E5 series, it's the better choice.

Comment: But it has worked. Why?

Comment: Sometimes things start to work by accident, but reproducing and controlling the behavior proves to be a lot more difficult. I'd say that is lost valuable lifetime, therefore my suggestion.

Comment: I can't use hotspots - my laptop has a problems with Wi-Fi too. Is there any USB 3.0 modems?

Comment: This has nothing to do with USB 3.0 nor would it be the solution. I suggest you get a better WiFi card for that notebook, too. Like one from Intel.

Comment: Hm... I see USB 3.0 has compatibility with 2.0. I think that modem can work with 3.0 (also, as I've said, it worked sometimes).

Answer (score 8):

I found out accidentally that my Tata Photon E1552/E1800 does not work as a modem on Mint 13 if connected to USB 3.0 port, but works wonderfully when connected via a USB 2.0 port on the same machine.

In fact, when connected to the USB 3.0 port on the motherboard, it is detected as a 12d1:1446, and refuses to switchover as a modem. When plugged into a USB 2.0 port on the same motherboard, it is seen as a 12d1:140b, and the network manager automatically takes it up as a modem.

I tested it on another machine running XUbuntu and it gave the same results. Works like a charm on the USB 2.0 port, but not on USB 3.0.

Comment: Is there a reason for that behaviour? Because this is also happening with my Huawei K3765 in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and 13.04.

Comment: I have the same problem, except when plugging it into the USB 2.0 port it shows as 12d1:140c

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch/+bug/979697/comments/115
This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10, but not on Ubuntu 13.04 (hix)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after upgrade but after using this and reboot all went well again 
http://www.linuxportal.pl/newsbar/modem-huawei-e1820-problem-z-polaczeniem-id82041
I know it is in Polish but I found it easy to follow anyhow..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Moreover, since the article is in Polish (as you mention), you should definitely translate that to English over here. Otherwise, this answer adds little value to majority of users of this site.

Comment: OK I am sorry, and the solution does not always work so it was hasty to say it solved the problem. So still there must be a more stable solution somewhere.

Comment: I have done more trials and it seems like I found a stable solution. I updated the kernel to 3.9.4 and now the usb dongle get recognized the right way, both on usb3 and on usb2 ports. I used this link http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/05/linux-kernel-394-released-for.html